# Set aligning properties between views in different layouts

Tags: android, xml

I was creating a XML layout for my app and I needed to align a button below a text, but because i used a LinearLayout to align horizontaly some texts with the property weight, the button stayed in a different layout and now I define the property "android:layout_below" and it doesn't find the ID of the text. 
So, someone have any suggestion that could solve this problem without using Java?

Here's my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="text1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="text2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="text3"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:
The button has to be aligned with `text1`, the idea is to use three properties: align_left, align_right and align_below so the button have the same width of the text. And I have other views to set properties with the texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set id for LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3" >
```

and place the button under the layout using

```
android:layout_below="@+id/text"
```

To align the button under the first text you can enclose the text1 and the button with the vertical linear layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="3" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text2"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="text2"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text3"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="text3"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

   </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I can't align to the Layout itself, it has to be aligned with the first text. It's different. But I understand, i didn't say everything. I need more properties, that was just an example. I edited the question to better explain it.

Comment: Maybe with this kind of "columns" I can achieve what I want. I will try it, thanks. (The layout is quite complex so it will take some time, tomorrow I say something).